# How to find out the name of currently logged in user in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an ASP.NET application, which runs on machine 1.

When a user access that page from machine 2, I want to find out the user name, under which he or she is logged in on machine 2.

I tried to use

- `Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name`
- `Page.User.Identity.Name`
- `((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Name`
- `((WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).User`
- `Request.LogonUserIdentity.User`

but it doesn't work.

`Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name` returns `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`, `Request.LogonUserIdentity.User` - `S-1-5-17`, all others - empty strings. `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR` is the user on the machine, on which the web application runs, not the user on the client machine.

In `web.config` I disabled impersonation using

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="false"/>
```

What can I do in order to get the user name of the user, who accesses the web page?

Comment: Is IIS set up to use Authentication?  Sounds like Anonymous access is still enabled.

Comment: How can I find it out? Is it specified in the `web.config`?

Comment: No, it's a server-side setting.  You can read more [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733010(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Actually , I would just like to thank you for asking that question cause i would need it's answer in few days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the authentication in IIS to Windows Authentication (and probably disable all others):

[image]

Go to:

- Website
- IIS - Authentication
- Edit according your wishes

Comment: I have the same problem, but wen I Enable windows Authentiation and disable all other, get 401 (Challenge) response.

Comment: Maybe your browser doesn't send the authentication well, or you are not part of the domain.